# NodeJS User Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am stuck at one point in NodeJs. I will explain my system step by step.

1. User registers to system
2. Backend create a JWT token and sends it to user
3. User stores jwt token in **local storage**
4. I want to go /profile page while user logged in.
5. User clicks a button which sends http post to /api/profile
6. Our http request has sent to /api/profile now. Router and authorization part is below
7. If user passes this authorization step. My /api/profile function returns res.json({success : true})
8. Im checking http response value with response.data.success === true. If its true, send user to /profile page. If not, send user to /login page.

**Here is the problem**

If user enters /profile to url bar, user can go directly to that page because there is no authorization control due to missing http.post request.

How can i check if user entered /profile while logged in or not?

My functions are below.

## HTTP POST

```
var profile = function () {
    var token = $window.localStorage.getItem('jwt')
    return $http.post('/api/profile',  {'token': token}).then(function (response) {
        if(response.data.success === true){
                $window.location.href = "/profile";
        }else{
                $window.location.href = "/login";
        }
    });
}
```

---

## PROFILE PAGE

```
exports.profilePage = function (req, res) {
    categoryModel.find(function (err, allCategories) { //NOT TO LOSE MENS OR WOMENS FROM NAVBAR !
        res.render('profile', {
            allCategories: allCategories
        })   
    });
}
```

## /API/PROFILE

```
exports.profile = function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        success: true
    })
}
```

---

## ROUTER

```
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
app.get('/profile', userController.profilePage);
app.post('/api/profile', userController.authenticate, userController.profile);  //AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED
```

## AUTHORIZATION

```
exports.authenticate = function (req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token
    if (token != null) { //To know that user logged in
        var user = userDBModel.User().methods.verifyJWT(token)
        if (user) {
            return next()
        } else {
            return res.json({
                success: false
            })
        }
    } else {
        return res.json({
            success: false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `My problem is` and `Here is the problem` wich of these problems exactly does not work? Also you have set only authorization check for post requests, not the GET requests.

Comment: But window.location.href is not a http request. Should i make a http request inside a http request?

Answer (score 0):

Could the connect-ensure-login package work for you in this instance? I use this with JWT/Express to redirect to login if a token is not found.

https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login

Comment: I'll look it up. Thank you for your answer